# Generate index with tuple

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm generating an index value associated with each tuple value :

```
a = ["what" , "a" , "test"]

c = 0
d = []
for b in a : 
    d.append((c , b))
    c = c + 1

print(d)
```

generates :

```
[(0, 'what'), (1, 'a'), (2, 'test')]
```

Is there Python idiomatic / functional way to implement same functionality ?

Something like :

```
list(map(lambda x : (x , c+1) , a))
```

Comment: yes, use `enumerate(iterable)`

Comment: So, `list(enumerate(a))`

Comment: Note, in Python, "idiomatic / functional" is a bit of an oxymoron: generally, while Python does support functional constructs, it is an idiomatically procedural language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`list(enumerate(a))` should give you what you want